# trying to import a zip character models from the models resource.com

Tags: modeling, import

So I've been trying to import a model of a inkling and octoling from the models resource website, I saved the model in zip file as that was the only way and also put it in a file in my desktop, I cant seem to actually find the models inside my actual file I put them in even though it appears in the files menu for blender, I've seen people do it but I don't know how to myself, I'm on windows 11.

Comment: First you need to extract the zip file. Then look for a DAE, FBX, or OBJ file that you can import into Blender. Use the menu *File > Import > ...* to import the specific file. Then you need to fix the material if it doesn't look right. Assign the textures files that are included in the zip file in the *Shader Editor*.